# Linked List methods in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to understand how .previous() method actually works.

In this line:

```
System.out.printf("%s ", a.previous());
```

It first prints the actual a item in line, then goes to the previous or it just gets the previous value?

Because l1.size() is 5, then the loop condition checks if the 5th position has a previous value?

Basically I just need to know how this works in order. Thank you in advance.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = {"apple", "bee", "orange", "noob", "win"};
    List<String> list1 = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (String s : a) {
        list1.add(s);
    }

    System.out.println("List1 Size: " + list1.size());

    reverse(list1);   
}
//reverse method
public static void reverse(List<String> l1) {

    ListIterator<String> a = l1.listIterator(l1.size());
    while (a.hasPrevious()) {
        System.out.printf("%s ", a.previous());
    }

}
```

Comment: When you read the Javadoc for the corresponding method(s) and class (`ListIterator`), what didn't you understand?

Comment: I am confused between indexes and size. While size is 5, `a.hasPrevious()` should start from the 5th element. Does it start counting from 0 or 1?

Comment: The javadoc of the `listIterator` overload you used states _An initial call to `previous` would return the element with the specified index minus one._

Answer (score -1):

`a.previous` gets the value that comes directly before the current value. It does this by first checking if the current `a` has a value that comes directly before it (i.e. a node that points at the value `a`). If it does, it then returns the value. Which then in turn is printed by your `System.out.println`